# Makefile command substitution does not accept parameters

Tags: go, makefile

I am trying to create a simple `Makefile` for my `go` project.

The following command substitution

```
GO_BUILD     := 'go build -ldflags "-s -w" -a -installsuffix cgo'


.PHONY: backup
build-cli:
    @$(GO_BUILD) -o cli ./cli
```

seems to create the following problem

```
▶ make build-cli
make: go build -ldflags "-s -w" -a -installsuffix cgo: No such file or directory
make: *** [build-cli] Error 1
```

What is the syntactically correct way of substituting `go build -ldflags "-s -w" -a -installsuffix cgo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the superfluous quotes from the variable should do it:

```
GO_BUILD     := go build -ldflags "-s -w" -a -installsuffix cgo
```

Otherwise, the shell (that `make` spawns) sees this command line:

```bash
'go build ...' -o cli ./cli
```

It correctly treats the whole string `go build ...` as `argv[0]` and tries to find it as an executable.